# Javascript - how to get the key value in if condition using AND (&&) operator

Tags: javascript, typescript, operators, and-operator

Is that possible to get the data like that

my sample code for the multiple And Or condition

```
var dataset =  { "dataone": "dataonevalue", "datatwo": "datatwovalue", "datathree:"" }
```

```
switch (dataset.dataone && dataset.datatwo && dataset.datathree) {
      case "":
      case null:
      case undefined:
        console.log("data missing")
        break;
      default:
        dataset.dataone = "dataonevalue"
        dataset.datatwo = "datatwovalue"
        dataset.datathree = "datathreevalue"
    }
```

I have to show which key has the "" or null or undefined and I have to get the particular key in which any of the three is found in Json object

for example like this

```
console.log("data missing in datathree")
```

How to do that ?... Can anyone please help me to solve this ?

Comment: 1: your `let dataset = {` ... is invalid syntax ... 2: `dataone` `datatwo` etc are undefined ...

Comment: Why does it have to be a `switch`? Some form of loop would be a lot more natural fit for the problem.

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply and Is there any way to solve this ? @deceze

Comment: ```Object.entries(dataset).forEach(([k, v]) => { if (!v) console.log(`${k} data missing`); })```…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to show which key has the "" or null or undefined and I have to get the particular key in which any of the three is found in Json object

Try this:

```js
let dataset = {
  "dataone": "dataonevalue",
  "datatwo": "",
  "datathree": null
};


for (const item in dataset) {
  let value = dataset[item];
  if (value === "") {
    console.log(`"${item}" is empty`);
  } else if (value === null) {
    console.log(`"${item}" is null`);
  } else if (value === undefined) {
    console.log(`"${item}" is undefined`);
  }
}
```

Hopefully this will help you!